# Why doesn't method dispatch work on the same candidate included from different sources?

Tags: generics, julia, dispatch

I'm quite baffled by this error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching 
correct_field(::Main.Poetry.LoadTemplates.TicketTemplates.myStruct, ::Dict{String, Any})
Closest candidates are:
  correct_field(::Main.Poetry.ContentGen.TicketTemplates.myStruct, ::Any)
  (...)
```

The problem is that I loaded the `structs` in `LoadTemplates` and now I am using a generic function from `ContentGen` that dispatches on those structs.

How is this usually solved? I guess I can "unmodulate" my Julia files. Or maybe there's a way to chop off all those `Main.Poetry...` to get just `TicketTemplates.myStruct`.

Finally, I'd like to know what's behind this design decision and what are the use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
module MyModule
include(“mystructs.jl”)
using .MyStructs
end
```

I ought to do:

```
include(“mystructs.jl”)
module MyModule
using Main.MyStructs
end
```